# Getting single time series from AWS CloudWatch metric maths SEARCH function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm attempting to creating a CloudWatch alarm for if any instances in a group go over x% of memory used and have built the following metric maths query to do so:

`SEARCH('{CWAgent,InstanceId} MetricName="mem_used_percent"', 'Maximum', 300)`

This graphs fine, however the CloudWatch console complains "The expression for an alarm must create exactly one time series.". I believe this is the case; The query above should (and does) return a singular line graph result that is not multi-dimensional.

How can I get this data to return in the format required by CloudWatch to create an alarm? My alternative is to general a new alarm per instance creation, however this seems more complex to manage the creation and destruction of alarms.

CloudWatch config on instance for collecting metric:

```
  "metrics":{
    "append_dimensions": {
      "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
    },
    "metrics_collected":{
      "mem": {
         "measurement": [
           "used_percent"
        ]
      },
      "disk": {
         "measurement": [ "used_percent" ],
         "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
         "resources": [ "/" ]
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create an alarm based on a search expression, so I don't think there's (currently) a way to do what you're after.

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html:

> You can't create an alarm based on the SEARCH expression. This is because search expressions return multiple time series, and an alarm based on a math expression can watch only one time series.

This appears to be the case even when you only get one result from a SEARCH expression.

I tried to combine this down into one time series using AVG, but this then appeared to lose the context of the metric and instead gave the error 'The expression for an alarm must include at least one metric'.

I'm currently handling a similar case with a pair of Lambda functions tied to CloudTrail events for `RunInstances` and `TerminateInstances`, that parse the event data for the instance ID and (among other things) create and delete individual CloudWatch alarms.

Comment: Actually - there might be a way... adding this as a comment rather than in the answer because I haven't tested it, but I note you're using CloudWatch agent; you may be able to set `aggregation_dimensions` to `[]` in the config file to just combine all the instances into one metric there. More details at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Metricssection

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only had one time series being returned by `SEARCH`. I used `SUM` to convert it from multiple time series to a single one which seems to have done the trick. If you have multiple time series, this won't work.

Something like `SUM(SEARCH(...))`. Your mileage may vary depending on what your `SEARCH` call returns.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to achieve by nesting [MathExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudwatch/MathExpression.html) to aggregate into single timeseries.

Cloudwatch metric search can be written as a Metric Insight query, so I'm using SQL for this example.

CDK example but analogous concepts apply for AWS Console:

```
        // create first timeseries metric from a MathExpression
        const your_query = "SELECT <cpu_utilization> FROM EC2 GROUPBY <id>"

        const timeseries_metric: IMetric = new MathExpression({
            expression: your_query, // or any expression conforming to type
            usingMetrics: {},
            label: "q1"
        })

        // collapse prior metric into single series
        const max_function = "MAX(q1)" 

        const alarm_metric: IMetric = new MathExpression({
            expression: max_function, // or aggregation best for your case
            usingMetrics: {"q1": timeseries_metric},
            label: "your_metric",
        );

        // then create alarm on resulting metric
        alarm_metric.createAlarm({ ... })
```

Since the hard limitation is against multiple timeseries (which also result from metric queries using GroupBy), it must be aggregated before it can be used in alarm (wrapped in Metric Math). Further, [only limited SQL is available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-math.html) and subqueries are not supported, making a nested MathExpression structure necessary.

Note also that only the last 3 hours worth of data is alarmable for queries.

Answer (score -1):

This example displays one line for each instance in the Region, showing the CPUUtilization metric from the AWS/EC2 namespace.

```
SEARCH(' {AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization" ', 'Average', 300)
```

Changing InstanceId to InstanceType changes the graph to show one line for each instance type used in the Region. Data from all instances of each type is aggregated into one line for that instance type.

```
SEARCH(' {AWS/EC2,InstanceType} MetricName="CPUUtilization" ', 'Average', 300)
```

Removing the dimension name but keeping the namespace in the schema, as in the following example, results in a single line showing the aggregation of CPUUtilization metrics for all instances in the Region.

```
SEARCH(' {AWS/EC2} MetricName="CPUUtilization" ', 'Average', 300)
```

refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html) for detailed explanation about search query.

To select metrics, refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html) link for step-by-step explanation.

Comment: thanks @Keyur Shrimali. However the issues isn't the amount of lines, the issue is the amount of time series. The third example you posted (removing the InstanceType) creates a singular line, but a multi time series, which cannot be used to create a CloudWatch alarm. As mentioned in the question "The query above should (and does) return a singular line graph result that is not multi-dimensional"