# How do you dynamically monitor custom metrics on autoscaled instances in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

A common scenario is to have instances automatically created in EC2 via autoscaling groups or via custom CLI/SDK calls. I have configurations of both.

I wish to monitor either the individual memory usages or the maximum memory within the group of instances to trigger a CloudWatch alarm if it goes over a threshold. Previously [I tried to create a metric maths search function to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363041/getting-single-time-series-from-aws-cloudwatch-metric-maths-search-function), to no avail. The idea being that the function would amalgamate all instances that matched X and find the maximum.

How can custom metrics such as memory or others collected via the CloudWatch Agent be monitored via an alarm? Is dynamic creation/deletion upon autoscale trigger possible (hopefully avoiding orphans), or is there an alternative best practice to this?

Comment: If you want max ram usage in a group, why your instances report individual metrics? They should all intect custom metrics under one name, so you have only one output metric to worry about.

Comment: thanks @Marcin, I'm not sure if I understand. How would I have all instances report under a single metric name?  Do you mean configuring all dimensions to have the same value so that the memory data for any within that dimension reports to the same metric?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. All instances report ram usage to the same dimension.